# affect a variable to a dataframe column in python 3

Tags: python, windows, pandas

I have a Dataframe sorted by id and time, please see below :

```
ID  TIME    VAR 1   VAR 2  
001   1h     x          1
001   2h     y          2
001   3h     x          1  
001   4h     z          1
002   1h     x          1
002   2h     x          2
002   3h     z          1
```

I would like to append a variable CR with that condition :

```
 - if for a same id, it(the id) already had VAR2 = 2, and after that, VAR1 = X. 
 -  Then CR = 1, else 0.
```

The final df should be like this :

```
ID   TIME  VAR 1   VAR 2   CR
001   1h    x        1      0
001   2h    y        2      0
001   3h    x        1      1 
001   4h    x        1      1
002   1h    x        1      0
002   2h    x        2      0
002   3h    z        1      0
```

I don't know how we can take the historic values for an ID and affect the values 1.

I think with 2 loops it's possible, i managed to create a ranking for TIME, but not for ID. I tried that code :

```
`cumul = 1
 i=1
 while i < df.USER_ID.count() : 
    if df.USER_ID[i:(i+1)] == df.USER_ID[(i+1):(i+2)]:
        cumul == cumul 
    else :
        cumul +=1
    i +=1`
```

it displayed that error : The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message hints, do (if you want all to match all):

```
cumul = 1
i=1
while i < df.USER_ID.count() : 
  if df.USER_ID[i:(i+1)].all() == df.USER_ID[(i+1):(i+2)].all():
      cumul == cumul 
  else :
      cumul +=1
  i +=1
```

Although you should know also that `df.USER_ID[i:(i+1)]` and `df.USER_ID[(i+1):(i+2)]` are Series of exactly one element, python operates on [start, end), i.e. [start, end-1] ranges. Which basically means that `df.USER_ID[i:(i+1)]` is `df.USER_ID[i]`.

And also surprised you don't get other problems later as your while loop should be `i+1 < df.USER_ID.count()` leaving the last element unprocessed of course.